# Why gcc complains a library can't be found while it's already there?

Tags: c, linux, linker, centos, shared-libraries

The messages are below:

```
$:~/software/version_1.02/example$ gcc -Wall -Wextra example.c -I../include -L../lib -lnnmf -larpack -llapack \
-lblas -o main
In file included from example.c:47:
../include/nmfdriver.h:92:7: warning: no newline at end of file
example.c:53: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’
example.c:53: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -larpack
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
$:~/software/version_1.02/example$ ls /usr/lib/*arpack*
/usr/lib/libarpack.so.2  /usr/lib/libarpack.so.2.0.0
```

The `arpack` is installed by `yum` (package manager). I was wondering why it can't be found.
Does anyone have ideas about how to solve this?

Comment: Might look for `libarpack.so` without version. Perhaps you need the `dev` package or a symlink.

Comment: you have to find if `libarpack` is present in `../lib` or the default library paths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be looking for the libraries without the version suffixes.
Try making a link without a version suffix to one of the versioned ones:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/arpack.so.2 /usr/lib/arpack.so
```